# Select previous 3 months

Tags: mysql, datediff, period

I am looking to select tickets from the previous 3 months.  By calculate the previous 3 months.
I saw this post:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7268896/calculate-3-month-period-using-mysql

But it does not seem to work.
Here is my query

```
select `created`, datediff( now(), `created`) as period , now()
from tag
having period%90=0;
```

But this is returning dates such as

```
created             period  now()  
2009-10-25 12:42:15 1170    2013-01-07 10:15:37
```

any ideas?
thanks

Comment: having without a group by seems a bit odd. Why not just put the datediff in the where clause instead of defining a period field?

Comment: `period % 90 = 0` means periods that are evenly divisible by 90.

Comment: The original question you linked (and its answer) are a bit misleading; I have closed it.

Answer (score 1):

% is the modulus operator so divides period by 90 and is the remainder tested... ie. 0,90,180,270,... will all return 0.

I think you need

`period < 90`

for all entries within the last 90 days.  If you just want 30 days only period = 90 would do.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `DATE_SUB()` to get a previous date. In your case, you'll want to use `DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 3 MONTH)`.

`SELECT FROM tag WHERE DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 3 MONTH) < created`

---

**Edit:** added an alternative for `DATE_SUB()` as requested below

Alternatively, you can use the following (there might be a much neater way to do this that I currently can't think of):

`STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT(DAY(NOW()), '-', MONTH(NOW()) + IF(MONTH(NOW()) > 3, -3, +9), '-', YEAR(NOW()) + IF(MONTH(NOW()) > 3, 0, -1)), '%e-%m-%Y')`

Comment: This seems pretty good


     select `created`, datediff( now(), `created`) as period , now()
     FROM tag 
     WHERE DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 3 MONTH) < created

Let me ask a followup

Using "INTERVAL 3 MONTH"
October has 31 days, Nov has 30 days, Dec has 31 days.
Does the MONTH interval use 30 days always?  Does it figure out the proper amount of days?

thanks

Comment: It does appear that INTERVAL 3 MONTH is really 90 days.  mysql does not seem to figure out that Oct has 31, Nov has 30 days, etc...

Since my report runs on the first of the month, every month,
would there be a way to just generate - 3 months back?  So if the report ran on 1-1-2013 to manually figure out 10-1-2012.  instead of INTERVAL 3 MONTH - really 90 days.  giving 10-3-2012 to 1-1-2013

Comment: I suppose that instead of using the `DATE_SUB()` function, you could also create the date as a string, and then let MySQL parse it. I've added an example in my post above.